# On iPad or iPhone, I take a snapshot of the screen looking at the screen sideway, but the snapshot is taken to be in Portrait mode?

Tags: iphone, ipad

On iPad or iPhone, I take a snapshot of the screen looking at the screen sideway (Landscape mode), but the snapshot is taken to be in Portrait mode?  So if I send this photo to a friend or post it on Facebook, it will be 90 degree off...

(I mean taking a snapshot by pressing the Power and Menu button at the same time)

Any fix or hack to make it work better?  (this also looks like a bug that might be able to go into future release of iOS)

I can upload it to the computer and use the computer to turn it 90 degree... but what if there isn't a computer around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to rotate images imported from a camera in iOS' Photos, so the functionality is there. For some reason it's not enabled for synced images or screenshots.

Instead of using a computer you can rotate images with an app providing the functionality. I think Myles also means this approach. Some free apps capable of image rotation:

- [PhotoPad](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photopad-by-zagg/id364758617)
- [Adobe Photoshop Express](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adobe-photoshop-express/id331975235)

Answer (score 0):

The only to fix this problem is to open the Photo in one of the photo editing applications (such as Photoshop Express) and rotating the photo 90 degrees.

Comment: yeah as I said, there might not be a computer around, and iPad should not depend on having another computer to "make it work"